# Change .innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change or add: data-dismiss="modal" to the innerHTMl of a button from within a `<script type="text/javascript">`.

```
<button type="button" id="verifyButton" name="verifyButton" data-dismiss="" onclick="VerifyMembership()" class="btn btn-primary" >Verify Membership #</button>
```

The first time the button is clicked it goes to the onclick function

```
function VerifyMembership() {                                               
document.getElementById("verifyButton").className = "btn btn-success";
document.getElementById("verifyButton").innerHTML = ('Continue <i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
```

Im wondering how to change or add `data-dismiss="modal"`to the innerHTML ?
The 2nd time the button is clicked it changes to a "continue" then needs to close a "modal" alert.

Comment: `document.getElementById("verifyButton").setAttribute('data-dismiss', 'modal')`

Comment: You appear to have a misconception as to what [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is. It does not change the attributes of the current element.  It "sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the *element's descendants*."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById("verifyButton").setAttribute("data-dismiss", "Modal-or-anything");

Answer (score 1):

You can set attribute as `document.getElementById("verifyButton").setAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");` or may be `document.getElementById('verifyButton').dataset.dismiss = "modal"` works